# best way to read post request from a tcp socket?

Tags: c, http, post, networking

i am writing a web server in c. i am working with TCP sockets and i want to know how to read post request and put it into a buffer.

what i can do is first read the post header in a buffer with fixed length and then create a dynamic buffer based on the content_length and read the body in dynamic buffer. but as the size of post header can vary, after read, the buffer containing the header could also contain body of the post request. i can try to parse it further but would it be efficient to do that?
is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You need to define "best". Fastest? Least memory consuming? Most readable/maintainable design? Most portable (endianess, alignment etc considerations)? As it stands, your question is too subjective and asking for opinions. Generally these kind of questions benefit from a code example of what you are currently considering, even if it's not working code or just pseudo code.

Comment: First write something that works. Then worry about the best way, and refactor it later on.

Comment: I'd create a buffer large enough to hold any possible header line and any possible *individual* key/value pair. Then I'd always fill all of the remaining buffer (which is the entire one initially), parse the current header line or key/value pair and `memmove` the unparsed part towards buffer front, then restart filling the buffer. A bit more advanced: Allocate the buffer dynamically (`malloc`) and if you discover that data is missing to fully parse the line or key/value pair then `realloc` and read more data.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in your case, i would say that the 'best way' is to separate each step into its own process.

First, in order to parse the message, you continuously have to read **raw** bytes from the underlying device (file, socket, pipe, etc) and 'feed' the parser, until the message is complete.

Parsing the message could also be divided into different steps:

- parsing the start line
- parsing the headers
- parsing the body (if any)

Since each step involves processing bytes of unknown size (separated by delimiter and not size specific, unless we already have 'parsed' the content length and know the body size), each process has its own needs of buffers, e.g.

- the start line is composed of <*method*> <*url*> <*version*> `\r\n`
- the header is composed of <*key*> `:` <*value*> `\r\n`
- the composition of the body is determined by the headers
- and the complete message does have the form <*header*> `\r\n` <*body*>, where the body part is optional (content length is zero)

So, long story short: you have to divide your message parser into different processing steps (highly recommended if you want to avoid spaghetti code) and decide when to use fixed sized or reallocatable buffers and how to reuse them (if not strictly separated by each step). Once you've done that and have a presentable implementation, then we're able to debate on how to reduce the usage of memory allocations and reuse of buffers.